# How to solve conditional equation involving the normal cdf

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Given $$X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$$

Find the smallest $\alpha$ for

$$P(x \leq 10) \geq \alpha$$

Such that the following is true

$$P(x \leq 10 - c) \geq \beta$$

where $\beta > \alpha$ < 1 and $c$ is a positive constant.

This is an exercise I came up with myself, so I am not even sure if there is a unique solution to the problem. Can you please help?

Comment: What is $P(X - 10) \geq \alpha$? Do you mean $P(X - 10 \geq \alpha) \geq ..$ or what?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an edit): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance

Comment: @G.Gare, sorry I forgot a leq-sign. Now it should be corrected.